# how to find work item that are assigned by me?

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2010 I want to see how many work items I have assigned. There is no 'Assigned by' filters. How can I achieve this?

I have tried history but that is too vague.

Comment: Are you doing this programatically or in the work item queries area of tfs? And do you mean work items you have assigned to you or that you have assigned to someone else?

Comment: So I have work item query for the tasks that are "Assigned to" @ME. I want to create a query which tells me which TFS work item I have assigned? May be I am looking for "Assigned by" filter. To elaborate more, lets say I have assigned 100 tickets to 10 members, how do I find those tickets and assigned persons?

Comment: As far as I know you would need to look at WorkItemHistoryView in SQL Server and match up where System_ChangedBy is you and the Syzstem_AssignedTo field has changed. I don't think you can necessarily get this info right out of the box.

Comment: You could also look at the System_Rev filed in WorkItemHistoryView but that doesn't guarantee that the person originally assigned to was the actual assign person. Sometimes people forget to change the assigned to field, save it then remember and then save again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the query. First select the 'Changed by' filter to @Me and then add the second filter 'Assigned to' with 'Does Not Contain' Operator with @Me value.
This will give you all the work-items you have assigned to others excluding you.